# Unhandeled exception when I try to open /_layouts/listsedit.aspx on a picture library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I ran into a weird problem and I was hoping someone could help me here.

In my SharePoint environment I try to go to the listsettings of a Picturelibrary, this always worked and now I get the following error in the event viewer:

==================================================================================

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 16-2-2011 15:10:20 
Event time (UTC): 16-2-2011 14:10:20 
Event ID: 55496074eecb4aeb91da5971f6415b14 
Event sequence: 1781 
Event occurrence: 86 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/607573788/ROOT-1-129423354556841301 
    Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ 
    Machine name: (hidden on purpose)

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7412 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: (hidden on purpose)

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://(hidden on purpose)/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=86BA0C356F3An unhandled exception has occurred.D0484An unhandled exception has occurred.D43F8An unhandled exception has occurred.D86CAAn unhandled exception has occurred.DBDDAAE88702A86D 
    Request path: /_layouts/listedit.aspx 
    User host address: (hidden on purpose) 
    User: (hidden on purpose) 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: (hidden on purpose)

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 12 
    Thread account name: (hidden on purpose) 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ListEditPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at ASP._layouts_listedit_aspx.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

==================================================================================

I'm not sure what's causing this behaviour. Weird thing is that it's only giving this error on the root sitecollection and not in the subsites. It's also only giving this error on Picturelibraries. Custom Lists and Document Libraries are about fine.

I can make views and add columns on those picture libraries, I just cannot open the listedit.aspx.

Hope someone can help me out here.

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Have you customised any content types used by the Picture Libraries in the root of the site collection? i.e. adding custom columns?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not use custom content types. When I create a new Picture library at the root of the site collection, the same error occur.

Comment: I have the same problem - in any library on a brand new web application.  If I find the answer, I will let you know!

Comment: Well, since I had just created my first sites, I disconnected from the farm, deleted all the sites I had from iis, and created a new farm.  I discoverd that in iis7, I had to have .net2 set as the default, not .net4.  That set everything in order.